# Perl - Capture Specific number of words from a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a lengthy string in a perl variable which has more than 500 words.

```
$mytext = "This text goes on and on and on........";
```

Basically, this lengthy string can contain anything and everything including all kinds of special characters. It can include special characters (like apostrophes - it's a division of cleo's business), numbers (like - incorporated on August 2, 2001), commas, semicolons and apostrophe's (like - through its different divisions, the business's earnings), special characters (like '&', single and double quotes)

My requirement is to extract a specific number of words (not characters) from the start of the string. For example, I may need to pick the first 200 words.
I know that there is a builtin `substr` function:

```
substr($mytext, $start, $length)
```

but it extracts the number of characters.
How can I extract the number of words instead?

Comment: `(?:\w+\s){199}\w+` ? maybe `\S` instead of `\w` if there are non-word, non-space characters

Comment: What is a "word" for you? What characters are allowed?

Comment: @Toto, a word can be anything. It can include special characters (like apostrophes - it's a division of cleo's business), numbers (like - incorporated on August 2, 2001), commas, semicolons and apostrophe's (like - through its different divisions, the business's earnings), special characters (like '&', single and double quotes)

Comment: Is a short definition like "every character that is not a space" correct for you?

Comment: @Toto, yes that is correct.

Comment: Good -- and important -- clarification in the edit.  In the future I recommend to try to specify such requirements right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's OK to define a word by all character that is not a space, you can do:

```
my $str = <<'EOD';
Basically, this lengthy string can contain anything and everything including all kinds of special characters. It can include special characters (like apostrophes - it's a division of cleo's business), numbers (like - incorporated on August 2, 2001), commas, semicolons and apostrophe's (like - through its different divisions, the business's earnings), special characters (like '&', single and double quotes)
EOD

my ($wd) = $str =~ /((?:\S+\s+){1,30})/; # I've limited the length at 30 for testing.
say $wd;
```

**Output:**

> Basically, this lengthy string can contain anything and everything including all kinds of special characters. It can include special characters (like apostrophes - it's a division of cleo's business), numbers

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [the `split` function](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) :

- it accepts a regexp : here `\W+` will split the string everytime a non-word character (or sequence of such characters) is encountered
- it offers an option that limits how many times the string will be cut (which effectively controls the maximum number of parts that you have in the output).

Code :

```
my $mytext = "This text goes on and on and on........";
my $nb_words = 20;
my @words = split(/\W+/, $mytext, $nb_words + 1);
pop @words; # the last item contains the remaining of the string
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, though your solution works equally well, the one by Toto makes a better fit for my stated requirement. Plus 1 to your solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a part of the text containing the first N words, with all the spaces, punctuation, etc

```
my $text = q(one two, three-four five etc);
my $n = 4;

my ($subtext) = $text =~ /((?:\w+.*?){$n})/; 
say $subtext;
```

with the subtext string

```
one two, three-four
```

Adjust what you consider a "word" in the regex. For example, if hyphens are acceptable change `\w+` to `[\w-]+` (in which case `three-four` is one "word" so `five` makes it in as well)

If you need a *list* of words, you can also "tokenize" (and capture) with a regex

```
my $n = 4;
my @words;

push @words, $1 while $text =~ /(\w+)/g and @words < $n;
say "@words";
```

for

```
one two three four
```

where you'd again change `\w` if your "words" are other than letters, numbers and underscore.